# Finding maxima and minima of $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2x^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, maxima-minima

Finding maxima and minima of $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2x^2$

I tried studying this exam problem but I need help in understanding it.

I found $f_{x}=4x^3-4x \\
f_y=4y^3$

From this, I get the stationary points $A(0,0)$, $B(1,0)$ and $C(-1,0)$

$f_{xx}=12x^2-4 \\
f_{yy}=12y^2 \\
f_{xy}=0$

Now after computing  $D(x,y)$ I got $D(A)=D(B)=D(C)=0$ which is inconclusive.

In the graph, it shows that the point $B$ and $C$ are local minimum.

I would really appreciate some good explanation because I have an exam soon and I would like some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function can be written as $$f(x,y)=(x^2-1)^2+y^4-1$$ and we have $$(x^2-1)^2+y^4-1\geq -1$$. And we can conclude that there is no maximum.($\infty$)

Comment: Okay I got that, but how to explain that we have a local minimum in $B$ and $C$

Comment: @J.Dane From indications in OP, the question only asks for the extremes of the function, and not necessarily where they're attained. But in this case since you have only finitely many possible points for the attainment of the minimum, and you know the latter, then it's easy to find where the minimum is attained.

Comment: @Allawonder Ohh I think I understand. Since $f(x,y) \ge f( \pm1, 0)$ then we have minimum in $B$ and $C$. Did I understand it right?

Comment: To show that there is no maximum can I say that since for very small $h \gt 0$ $f(h,h)=2h^4-2h^2 \lt 0= f(0,0)$, in the other hand we have $f(0,h)=h^4 \gt 0$ .Since the function changes sign there is no extremum. Hence there is no maximum

Comment: @J.Dane Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 4):

You can analyze the function by completing the square.

Note that $$x^4-2x^2+y^4=(x^2-1)^2+y^4-1$$

The minimum of $-1$ occurs at $$(x^2-1)^2+y^4=0$$
That is $x=\pm 1,y=0$

The critical point $(0,0)$ is a saddle point because you get both positive and negative values near that point where the value of your function is $0$

There is no local or absolute maximum.

Comment: @J.Dane I recommend this, especially the latter part.

Answer (score 0):

When can we say a point $v$ provides a local minimum on a smooth function $f$?

we can say so, if for every vector $w\neq 0$, we can say there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|t|<\epsilon$, $f(v+w)>f(v)$.

What you calculated is based on the fact that this can be said when the second directional derivative on $f$ is strictly positive everywhere.

However, the points $B,C$ have one bad direction, which is $y$-axis direction that gives us second derivative $0$. (it is strictly positive for every other direction)

Thus, we only need to concentrate on that direction.

Since $f(B+t(0,1))>f(B)$ for every $t\neq 0$, we can say $B$ is a local minimum point, and similar for $C$.

Now, $A$ is not a local minimum, since $f(\epsilon,0)<f(0,0)$ for every small $\epsilon>0$.